# How to configure user for worklist application and human workflow?

Tags: jdeveloper, bpel, business-process-management, soa-suite

I am new in SOA Suite and we are using SOA suite 11g. Please let me know how to configure user for human work flow and work-list application. I created simple users in weblogic realm. but how to set which user can be administrator or which user will be end user.

please refer some documents also.

Hi, thanks for suggesting, but I am so much confused. when creating a task in BPEL application we need to provider user information in assiginment tab. so here only those users listed they are in weblogic realm. but while creating user in weblogic I am not getting any option for making this user as administrator or end user. right now i have created user in weblogic and when I am creating task its getting in inbox of particular user also. but I need to verify this user can perform only end user roles. after this i want to create one more user say "ABC" as administrator. – Abhishek 6 hours ago

//adding comments

I am looking for, but when I am creating user in weblogic then only users are listing while creating Human task in my BPEL process. will you please tell me how to create users for worklist application. and the main problem is if I will create user in worklist and then how those user will be listed when creating Human Task.

just want to create two user , I will use them to login in work-list application, one for administration and one as a end user. All users what I am creating is showing administrative task tab. too much confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this chapter of the developer guide : 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10224/bp_worklist.htm#BHADHGCF

Have a look at this section "28.8.1 How To Manage Other Users' or Groups' Rules (as an Administrator)" : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10224/bp_worklist.htm#insertedID8

Edit :

Here the real solution :
Just follow this : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10226/hwf_config.htm#insertedID7.

From the weblogic console, go to securityRealms | myRealms | users& group 
Create a group , create your users, manage the users's group membership.

If I only set my new user in the new group, no administrative task tab is visible, but if I had the membership to the group labsupervisor, the tab is visible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggesting, but I am so much confused. when creating a task in BPEL application we need to provider user information in assiginment tab. so here only those users listed they are in weblogic realm. but while creating user in weblogic I am not getting any option for making this user as administrator or end user. right now i have created user in weblogic and when I am creating task its getting in inbox of particular user also. but I need to verify this user can perform only end user roles. after this i want to create one more user say "ABC" as administrator.

Comment: I am not sure, but the weblogic users are managed differently than the worklist app users.

Comment: thats I am looking for, but when  I am creating user in weblogic then only users are listing while creating Human task in my BPEL process. will you please tell me how to create users for worklist application. and the main problem is if  I will create user in worklist and then how those user will be listed when creating Human Task.

Comment: I found this : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10226/hwf_config.htm#BHCGJFJC

Comment: thanks, I just want to create two user , I will use them to login in work-list application, one for administration and one as a end user. All users what I am creating is showing administrative task tab. too much confused.

Comment: I just made a test : If I create a new group, a new user and him to the new group, no administrative task tab is visible.

Comment: Please tell me where you created this user. means group /user.

Comment: I just created a group in weblogic realm. then add user.when I am logging through that user, i am getting administrative task tab.

Comment: have a look at your worklist-app conf from the weblogic console : Summary of Deployments >worklistapp >/integration/worklistapp > Security > Roles

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but i faced similar issue. Go to your domains config directory and add the ldap provider in the default jps context in jps-config.xml and it will work like charm :-)

```
        <jpsContext name="default">
        <serviceInstanceRef ref="credstore"/>
        <serviceInstanceRef ref="keystore"/> 
        <serviceInstanceRef ref="policystore.xml"/>
        <serviceInstanceRef ref="audit"/>
        **<serviceInstanceRef ref="idstore.ldap"/>**
        </jpsContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties for setting Managers can't be edited in the web console.

You need a LDAP client to connect the Weblogic's LDAP. There you will see the property "manager" for each user. Just add the DN of the user you want to be the manager for the selected user.

You can follow this tutorial:

http://jvzoggel.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/weblogic-embedded-ldap-with-an-external-ldap-client/